# What is "amazonaws" virus? Do i have it?

Tags: virus

[image]I was browsing and clicked on a website and was redirected to a page with the URL (dont click it) "s3-app-southest-2.amazonaws" and a pop up saying i have a virus click here and all that other spam. My machine started beeping and i turned it off.

Attached, a screenshot someone else posted online of the same pop up.

Any solution? Cheers, Callum.[!][2]][2]

Comment: You should report this to the [AWS Abuse Team](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/report-aws-abuse/)

Comment: "Firefox detected a virus" - "The virus cannot be detected by Anti-Virus software". By this logic, Firefox would be the best Anti-Virus software out there.

Answer (score 4):

Your computer is very likely not infected with a virus.

Websites which claim that they just scanned your computer for viruses without your consent, found that it is infected with something and you need to pay lots of money for some product to get rid of it is a scam which appears since the early 2000s. It's quite surprising that there are apparently still people falling for it.

[Amazon Web Services (AWS)](https://aws.amazon.com/) is a cloud-based hosting provider where anyone can set up a website with very little effort. That's why it is frequently used by scammers.

Comment: Thanks, im running some virus scans so hopefully everything will be fine.